# How to get started on custom GUI widgets

Tags: c++, qt, widget, gtk3

I would like to exercise programming software with non-standard graphical interfaces such as the ones in the following images. I know how to create a GUI using basic widgets, but I have no idea on how to create my own custom widgets. I am familiar with GTK 3.0 and Qt. The GTK tutorial, for instance, has a link on how to do custom drawing. I just don't know if this is the usual and correct way to create custom widgets. There's also things such as: selections, mouse handling, zoom, scrolling, animations and so on that tutorials do not teach.

So here is my question: what kind of documentation, keywords, tutorials and algorithms should I look for? For my first project, I would like to start with something similar to the first and second images below. My current knowledge is C/C++ and Qt and GTK, but I can learn new languages and tools if necessary.

- http://hobby-electrons.sourceforge.net/tutorials/gEDA/simple-schematic-in-gschem.png
- http://www.cburch.com/logisim/docs/2.7/pt/html/images/screen-shot.png
- http://eeweb.poly.edu/labs/nanovlsi/tutorials/soctutorials/figures/ENCFinalDesign.gif
- http://www.ccm.ece.vt.edu:8088/etextiles/projects/arch_images/simulation.jpg
- http://j-algo.binaervarianz.de/images/avl_avltest.png

Comment: You forgot to search, right? [Creating Custom Widgets for Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Qt Graphics view Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html) is what you should use if you go with Qt. [There are several examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/examples-graphicsview.html) covering the basics of creating components.

To be able to mimic those samples, most of the work is going to be on implementing custom graphic view items. Like widgets it means providing a paint method, specialized event handlers and properties.